# Pandas - Get all rows that have same selected column values as specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code below and `features` is a list of column names and `filtered` is a Pandas dataframe. What I'm trying to do is given a specific row (index=0) in this case I'm trying to find all the rows with the same `features` values as row at index = 0. The below throws an error, but essentially the idea was to check each row and if it had the same `features` and row with index 0 then it would return those rows. The error it throws is `pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`

```
print(filtered[features].drop_duplicates().iloc[0][features])
print(filtered[filtered[features].eq(filtered[features].drop_duplicates().iloc[0][features]).all()])
```

Also tried:

```
for idx, row in filtered.iterrows():
    sub_filt = filtered[filtered[sub_features].eq(row[sub_features]).all(axis=1)]
    print(len(sub_filt))
```

and it prints all 0s, but it should be printing at least a 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, for create mask use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with `axis=1` :

```
d = {'c1': ['a','b','c','a','b','c'],
     'c2': [1,2,3,1,2,1],
     'c3':range(2,8)}
filtered = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    
features = ['c1','c2']

print(filtered[features].eq(filtered[features].iloc[0]))
      c1     c2
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
3   True   True
4  False  False
5  False   True

print(filtered[features].eq(filtered[features].iloc[0]).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
print(filtered[filtered[features].eq(filtered[features].iloc[0]).all(axis=1)])
  c1  c2  c3
0  a   1   2
3  a   1   5
```

Comment: Very nice use of pandas.dataframe.eq()

Comment: I made an edit to the post using your code for some reason it keeps returning 0 rows after the filter, but it should return at least 1.

Comment: @Gooby - So it means first row matched only few rows (maybe only first one), can you try change `for idx, row in filtered.iterrows():` to `for idx, row in filtered.iloc[:5].iterrows():` for test first 5 rows?

Comment: still all zeros sadly

Comment: @Gooby - testing my sample data by `for idx, row in filtered.iterrows():`  and change `features` to `sub_features` for me working well, can you test too?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

```
rows_based_on_condition = df[df["column"] == value]
```

When you're trying to apply it based on multiple columns, you can replace the input df (or a copy of the df) multiple times using a for-loop:

```
columns = ["column_1", "column_2"]
val_dict = dict()

for col in columns:
    val_dict.update({col:df.iloc[0][col]})

for key in val_dict.keys():
    value = val_dict[key]
    df = df[df[key] == value]
```

Also try to write your code in such a way, that each line only contains one step. Makes it easier to read.
This old project of mine, contains a good example at:
# reshaping wdi_df from wide to long form (<- copy into ctrl-F searchbar)
https://github.com/MaximilianHauser/CC_DS21_Life_Expectancy_and_GDP/blob/main/life_expectancy_gdp.ipynb
Also might be interesting if you're doing an online data science course.
Happy Coding!